# Run an asynchronous stream-based function synchronously in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am trying to create an engine for Browserify for use in Mincer.

Mincer is synchronous. Templates are rendered by a call to [`Template#evaluate`](https://github.com/nodeca/mincer/blob/master/lib/mincer/template.js) which requires the compiled template to be returned at the end of the function.

Browserify v2 is asynchronous.

Is this possible?

Please note: Control flow libs, Fibers, etc. will not work.

The solution I am looking at is using [execSync](https://github.com/mgutz/execSync) to work with the `browserify` cli util.

I would prefer to do it programmatically if possible.

Cheers!

---

UPDATE: Using [shelljs](https://github.com/arturadib/shelljs) now.